# PHP Inserting into mysql issue

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am having trouble when I run the following command:

```
$stmt = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO checked_in (attendee_id) VALUES (?)");
$stmt->bind_param("i", $id);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
```

This is part of a bigger page but this is the part that isn't working. I first pull the $id from the SQL database so I know I have a connection. I just can't seem to get this update part to work.

```
mysql > CREATE TABLE checked_in ( 
        id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
        attendee_id int NOT NULL,
        check_in_time TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
```

This is the code I am using to build the table. Am I doing something wrong? I think my problem is that it can talk to the database but I don't know if I set up the table wrong where it is expecting the id and the timestamp to be manually entered. It works if I am on my sql prompt and use this command

```
mysql> INSERT INTO checked_in (attendee_id) VALUES (1);
```

Here is the main part of the program (in the process of adapting the tutorial to my own):

```
function checkIn() {

    // Check for required parameters
    if (isset($_POST["phone"]))  {

        // Put parameters into local variables
        $phone = $_POST['phone'];

        // Look up code in database
        $user_id = 0;
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare('SELECT id, first, last, email FROM attendees WHERE phone=?');
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $phone);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($id, $first, $last, $email);
        while ($stmt->fetch()) {
            break;
        }
        $stmt->close();

        // Bail if number doesn't exist
        if ($id <= 0) {
            sendResponse(400, 'Invalid number');
            return false;
        }   

        // Check to see if this device already redeemed 
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare('SELECT id FROM checked_in WHERE attendee_id=?');
        $stmt->bind_param("i", $id);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($checkedInID);
        while ($stmt->fetch()) {
            break;
        }
        $stmt->close();

        // Bail if number already checked in
        if ($checkedInID > 0) {
            sendResponse(403, 'Number already checked in');
            return false;
        }

        // Add tracking of redemption
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO checked_in (attendee_id) VALUES (?)");
        $stmt->bind_param("i", $id);
        $stmt->execute();

        // Return unlock code, encoded with JSON
        $result = array(
            "checked_in" => "true",
        );
        sendResponse(200, json_encode($result));
        return true;
    }
    sendResponse(400, 'Invalid request');
    return false;
        }
}
```

Ok so I checked my apache error logs and this is what it is saying:

```
[Fri Jul 25 15:06:41.996107 2014] [:error] [pid 16824] [client 127.0.0.1:52699] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: db in /var/www/html/index.php on line 129
[Fri Jul 25 15:06:41.996171 2014] [:error] [pid 16824] [client 127.0.0.1:52699] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in /var/www/html/index.php on line 129
```

Comment: What error message does it give you?

Comment: It doesn't give an error, it just doesn't insert

Comment: Are you checking for them? If not, add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything.

Comment: check you php error log

Comment: Are you using this in conjunction with a form? How exactly are you using this? Show more code. Plus, use `mysqli_error($db);` depending on the DB variable. Which API are you using? Plus, try `$stmt = $db->prepare` instead of `$stmt = $this->db->prepare` it's hard to say what your DB connection is or if using a class.

Comment: I was following this tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/2941/how-to-write-a-simple-phpmysql-web-service-for-an-ios-app and got that working good but the problem came when I started to make my own. I will edit my post and give more code

Comment: You'll need to post your own code then. It's hard to say where the differences are.

Comment: Everything else is the same as the tutorial, I was just changing it so instead of redeeming a code it would allow a phone number to check in

Comment: Did error reporting yield anything? Plus, you are calling your `checkIn()` function, right?

Comment: Error reporting didn't show anything. Its more of an API so in the code the post isset won't let me see the error on page because I don't think it would ever get to that part of the code but when I do it in curl theres no error except when I tried the below answers which is mentioned in their comments

Comment: Yes I am calling that, that part is the same as the tutorial code (assign from just renaming it)

Comment: Your form element(s) is/are named? I.e.: `<input type="text" name="phone">` and using `form method="post"`?

Comment: aaron@aaron:~$ curl -F "phone=5852815098" http://localhost/
{"checked_in":"true"}

Comment: If I echo the $id it is set and correct by the way

Answer (score 4):

If you bind your parameters while using a question mark in your queries, then you shouldn't use `i` as parameter. Use a numeric parameter instead.

Try

```
$stmt->bind_param(1, $id);
```

From them [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php):

> For a prepared statement using named placeholders, this will be a
>   parameter name of the form `:name`. For a prepared statement using
>   question mark placeholders, this will be the 1-indexed position of the
>   parameter.

That said, please describe what `$id` is assigned to in this function.

Comment: After turning errors on I get this: 

mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Undefined fieldtype 1 (parameter 2) in <b>/var/www/html/index.php</b> on line <b>131</b><br />

Comment: The line you mentioned is line 131 by the way

Comment: If that doesn't work, try changing the question mark to something like `:value` and use this as bind parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$stmt = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO checked_in (attendee_id) VALUES (?)");
$stmt->execute( array( $id ) );
```

should work.

If you want to check the error, you should do:

```
$stmt = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO checked_in (attendee_id) VALUES (?)");
$check = $stmt->execute( array( $id ) );

if ( $check ) {
    echo 'Nice work!';
} else {
    $error = $stmt->errorInfo();
    echo $error[2];
}
```

Comment: It gives me this error: "mysqli_stmt::execute() expects exactly 0 parameters" and "Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::errorInfo()"